# Как подставить ID счетчика к yaCounter через JS?

Tags: javascript

Для сбора статистики по целям сайтов клиентов, нужно чтобы в встраиваемых формах была возможность добавить код цели, т.е. `yaCounter468648.reachGoal('order');`

У каждого клиента цель может быть названа по разному и ID счетчика разный. Для этого есть id в системе нужные они выгружаются при загрузке сайта клиента

**options.YaMetrikId** - ID счетчика яндекс метрики;

**options.YaMetrikGoals** - наименование цели;

сделал так:

```
yaCounter''+ options.YaMetrikId +''.reachGoal(''+ options.YaMetrikGoals +'');
```

Но потом понял, что неправильно!

**Как к yaCounter подставить id находящийся в options.YaMetrikId?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все переменные и функции, созданные в скрипте на странице, находятся в области видимости объекта `window` и являются его методами и свойствами, например:

```
var myVar = 'Моя переменная';
alert(myVar); //Моя переменная
alert(window.myVar); //Моя переменная
alert(window['myVar']; //Моя переменная
```

Вы практически правильно написали, но нужно обращаться к объекту window

```
window['yaCounter'+ options.YaMetrikId].reachGoal(options.YaMetrikGoals);
```